# Getting error when creating a PostgreSQL query with a CASE expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a script that checks if a process is active in PostgreSQL and if so, kills it using the active_pid and then drops the replication slot. If it is not active then it drops the replication slot right away.

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT active,
   CASE
      WHEN active = true
          then pg_terminate_backend(active_pid) AND pg_drop_replication_slot('slot_name')
          else pg_drop_replication_slot('slot_name')
          END
   from pg_replication_slots;
```

And I get the following error:

> `ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type void
>   LINE 4: ...        then pg_terminate_backend(active_pid) AND pg_drop_re...`

How could I perform this query?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using control structure for this requirement.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
        active_array boolean[];
        act boolean;

BEGIN
        SELECT ARRAY(SELECT active FROM pg_replication_slots) INTO active_array; 
        FOREACH act IN ARRAY active_array
        LOOP
            IF act = true
            THEN
               pg_terminate_backend(active_pid);
               pg_drop_replication_slot('slot_name');
            ELSE
               pg_drop_replication_slot('slot_name');
            END IF;

        END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am now getting the message: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "boolean"
LINE 2:         active_array boolean[];   (It shows the pointer in the boolean)

Comment: which posgresql version?